# Delphi Handle Android "Overview" button

Tags: delphi, button, onclick

Using Delphi Tokyo 10.2, is there a way to handle the OnClick event of the overview button (the button on the right of the android navigation bar)?

I was thinking about something like the code above:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
   if (Key = ...) then
   begin
      //do something
   end;
end;
```

Do you know the name of the overview button key?
Alternatively, is there a way to completely hide the navigation bar?

**Edit#1**
I found a temporary solution..Pressing the overview button calls the *FormSaveState* event, so I decided to handle my problem taking advantage of this method.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "completely." Apps hide the navigation bar all the time. (Look at Netflix, or Google Photos, for example.) You can still drag from the side of the screen to make it reappear, though.

Comment: It can be even hardware part of the device. So with a tool like hand saw you can completely hide it for sure :)

Comment: @RobKennedy I mean hide it permanently (no toggle mode)

Comment: @Victoria Sorry, what you mean with a tool like hand saw?

Comment: It's a joke. Use a saw to physically remove the buttons from the phone.

Comment: ah....ok very useful feedback....hahahah